# In iOS AVPlayer, addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval seems to be missing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

I'm trying to setup `AVPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval()`. Has anyone used this successfully?

I'm using Xcode 8.1, Swift 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [func addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval interval: CMTime, 
                       queue: DispatchQueue?, 
                       using block: @escaping (CMTime) -> Void) -> Any](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserver)

It is in the documents also for example check this code snippet

```
let timeObserverToken = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [unowned self] time in 
}
```

Referenced from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS/Listings/Swift_AVFoundationSimplePlayer_iOS_PlayerViewController_swift.html)

Comment: this is simply wrong, you can not "let" it ...

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer makes it feel like that you can assign the return value to a local variable and ignore it. But according to the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserver), it is actually important the hold on strong reference to the return value and `removeTimeObserver(_ :)`.

> You must maintain a strong reference the returned value as long as you want the time observer to be invoked by the player. Each invocation of this method should be paired with a corresponding call to 
>   removeTimeObserver(*:)
>   . Releasing the observer object without invoking 
>   removeTimeObserver(*:)
>    will result in undefined behaviour.

So I would do:

```
if let ob = self.observer {
    player.removeTimeObserver(ob)
}

let interval = CMTimeMake(1, 4) // 0.25 (1/4) seconds
self.observer = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] time in
    ...
}
```

Comment: The docs of removeTimeObserver note that the block called by addPeriodic... can sometimes be called even after we've called removeTimeObserver. I'm at a loss currently making sure that won't happen as I suspect that is causing some crashes going on when I remove a VC, even though I make sure to remove the time observer when dismissing the VC.

Comment: Without screaming hooray yet, and for anyone still watching, I seem to have fixed my crashing issue. After releasing the time observer on the avplayer, I also made sure to release/remove the avplayer itself from any object (including the view/layer using it), and it seems to keep the crashes away for at least a 50 or so tries. The crashing used to happen like every 10th try.

Comment: Not knowing the exact reason, but I suspect the AVPlayer comes back at a later point to call the block specified with `addPeriodicTimeObserver`. This would normally, and in my case, be the view controller. If the view controller is dismissed/deallocated before that happens, it will crash no matter if you released the observer or not. I did not find another way of doing it (playing with queues etc)